# JavaFX onEditStart Methods

Tags: java, javafx, tableview

I am learning JavaFX and there are no examples to the methods getOnEditStart() and setOnEditStart() on the Internet.

How can I use them to get the cell value? 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you referring to the `onEditStart` handler for a `TableColumn`?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do

```
column.setOnEditStart(event -> {
    T currentValue = event.getOldValue();
    // ...
});
```

Replace `T` with the type for your table column.